# Show and Hide Div on dynamic generated checkbox value using jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to fire an event (show and hide div) on dynamic generated checkbox (generated through Ajax).

I tried many events like window.onload, document.load etc but I did not get success.

I don't want to click anywhere. I am only fire event on page load or document load.

Can any expert please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you plz show us what have you tried that we could look?

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
$('body').on('yourEventGoesHere','.className',function(){
        ... event handler code ....
});
```

[Read more](https://aiocollective.com/blog/click-doesn-t-work-after-ajax-load-jquery/)

Comment: HI My friend..Thanks for your reply!! 

But I am not clicking any event. I want on load of page.